# Sails Framework + MongoDB set connection pool size

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, connection-pooling, sails-mongo

We are using sails framework for our web application and MongoDB as database.

Now we are calling services of the web app from the mobile.

There can be around 200-300 concurrent users calling webservice.

I observed that there are around 5-6 services executed and rest are ignore with time out exception.

I read somewhere that sails-mongo has default connection pool size 5.

How can I change it?

Here is config file. Though the connection pool size not changing.
mongodb: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url : 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb?poolSize=200'
  },

Answer (score 1):

I found poolSize configuration in [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L100) documention.

Can you try something like below.

```
  someMongoDb: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'localhost', // defaults to `localhost` if omitted
port: 27017, // defaults to 27017 if omitted
user: 'username_here', // or omit if not relevant
password: 'password_here', // or omit if not relevant
database: 'database_name_here' // or omit if not relevant
poolSize: 10 //or omit if not relevant
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this still not working. It looks like the sails framework limits the concurrent request.

I remove the fetching data from mongodb and just make the method empty without sending response.

I observe that it executes 4 requests and make other request for wait. If I kill one request it takes other waited request.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the sails framework limits the concurrent request. I
>   remove the fetching data from mongodb and just make the method empty
>   without sending response. I observe that it executes 4 requests and
>   make other request for wait. If I kill one request it takes other
>   waited request

Sails/node/mongodb are not the problem as they can handle thousands of simultaneous requests. Nodejs is configured to accept infinite number of sockets by default https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets.

Most likely your browser or http client is limiting the number of requests per server. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/985704/401025 or lookup the maximum number of requests from the manual of your http client.